# Primeng overwrite styles from component

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a component in html:

```
<app-terminate-product _ngcontent-c27="" _nghost-c37="">
   <p-overlaypanel _ngcontent-c37="" ng-reflect-style-class="overlay-content">
     <div class="overlay-content ui-overlaypanel........>
```

My html file:

```
    <p-overlayPanel [styleClass]="'overlay-content'">SOME INPUTS HERE</p-overlayPanel>
```

I want to to add something to ui-overlaypanel but it doesn't work in my TerminateProductComponent.scss:

```
.ui-overlaypanel { something: ..}
```

I also tried to add selector in my styles.scss, but it doesn't work..

```
.overlay-content .ui-overlaypanel {...}
```

How can I add styles to **.ui-overlaypanel** ?

Comment: .ui-overlaypanel { background-color: ##3071A9 !important; } it will be overwrite the styles

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new .css file, add all necessary changes to that file you want in `.ui-overlaypanel` and then load it AFTER primeng .css file is loaded. You can achieve it by simply editing the `.angular-cli.json` file. Find `styles` array in `angular-cli.json` and add your .css file after primeng one, for example:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "overwrite.css"
  ]
```

You can also use inline `[style]` like this:

```
<p-overlayPanel [style]="{'text-align': 'center', 'background-color': 'blue'}">SOME INPUTS HERE</p-overlayPanel>
```

Comment: This works for me, but I'd like to use the variables I have defined in my .scss brandbook, ehnce I'd like to overwrite the primeng styles in the scss next to my component. However, that hasn't worked for me so far...

Comment: Make sure to rebuild your project and clean browser cache, as this method may sometimes keep styles in cache.